Next JS App router got internal server error on getting every page
src/app/[locale]/page.tsx
import { Metadata } from "next"
import HomePage from "./Homepage"

export async function generateMetadata(
    { params }: any,
): Promise<Metadata> {
    let locale = params.locale

    return {
        title: locale === "zh" ? "Chinese Words" : "English Words"
    }
}

export default async function Home({
    params: {
        locale
    }
}: {
    params: any
}){ 
    return (
        <>
        <HomePage locale={locale} />
        </>
    )
}

src/app/[locale]/Homepage.tsx
"use client"
import "../../styles/home.css"

export default function HomePage({
    locale
}: {
    locale: string
}){ 
    return (
        <>
        Page Content goes here
        </> 
  );
}

In Next JS app with app router, since I used another separate component to render every page with title head, there is an issue occurred that GET http://localhost:3000/(base path)/zh 500 (Internal Server Error) whenever I access each page. May I ask why will this occur and how can I fix the error using this project structure?
